# How to create a Many-to-One relationship with existing records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations, reference

I'm trying to implement something similar to that below. Basic setup is a `Schedule` model

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

The `Event` model will then belong_to a `Schedule`. 
Events are comprised of a name, datetime, running length and a `Room`

A `Room` is chosen from a select list when the event is created, all Rooms are created beforehand through seeding or admin interface. Room will store information like seating count.

I've been trying to find a method implementing this that feels right. Solutions seem to range between habtm or has_many :through but I can't see the need for a join table for this situation.
Theoretically, an Event `has_one :room` but the reverse relationship isn't `belongs_to :event` as a Room may be used for many events, this also requires the foreign key to be on the rooms table.

I've considered handling this manually in the model using a room_id foreign key in the event, I could then query for the relevant Room. I think this would work since I currently cannot see a requirement for finding all events using a Room.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule

  def room
    Room.find(room_id)
  end
end
```

Everything I've done so far in Rails has felt 'right', but all the solutions I've come up with here doesn't and I feel like I'm missing something; or maybe I'm just expecting that extra bit of magic.
Is there a "Rails" way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't Event just have a belongs_to relationship to Room in this case?

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule
  belongs_to :room
end
```

If you think about it from a schema perspective, your "events" table almost certainly has "schedule_id" and "room_id" columns.

The other side of the relationship is that a Room has_many Events.

Comment: Just to add: it might help not to think of 'belongs_to' as implying ownership (as it does in English), but simply as 'has a' relationship. It implies the same relationship as 'has_one' - it's just that the foreign key is on a different table.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. I think I may have been over thinking the associations in Rails, particularly where `has_one` sounds like perfect match for the situation. I also got the location of the foreign keys mixed up in a has_many/belongs_to association. A nudge in the right direction and couple hours away helped.